# ArcScene 10.1 Orthophoto Visualization Issue

Tags: visualisation, arcscene, orthophoto

I am attempting to visualize an orthophoto in ArcScene 10.1 at the same resolution it is at in ArcDesktop 10.1. I have set the "Quality enhancement for raster images" to it's highest extent. But, the resolution is still low (i.e. it is very pixelated). In ArcDesktop I can see individual downed trees within the orthophoto, but within ArcScene I can barely see roads. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the "Display Quality" under Layer Properties > Display > Display Quality?

Comment: Yes, Display Quality is at it's highest setting (past Normal). I did notice when I check "Display raster resolution in table of contents" that the Res is 1:6.6677, but it should be 1:1 (I would think) after going to Base Heights > Elevation from surfaces > Raster Resolution... and setting Cellsize X and Y to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the result of the size and/or the file format. The orthophoto encompassed roughly 53,000 acres at 0.5-1 meter resolution. The file format was .ers/.ecw. After finding .tif files of the same area, they were mosaiced. These mosaiced photos covered a smaller geographic extent. While there does appear to be a reduction in quality between ArcDesktop and ArcScene, it is much less than previously experinced (i.e. 0.75-1.25 meter).